# Transition between divs ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm building a web app using ReactJS.

I'd like to implement something like this:

[image: Desired effect]

So my question is:

- **How is this effect called?**
- **How could I implement it?**

I don't want the code, I'd like really to learn how to, but I don't know how to look for it.

I've done all components I need, I just need to know how to implement this particular effect.
Of course, a simple "*look at this post*" will be apreciated too much.

According to the documentation given by Facebook, using JQuery is not a good practice when you are using ReacJS, that's why I don't know where to start.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Not related to react. https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Comment: As I said, i did not know where to start, that's why i assumed that maybe i could be related to react. Having said that, you have answered my question!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a *sticky header*, you can use [this library](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky) for an easy implementation with React.